# How to generate multiple impressions on a hyperlink through HtmlUnit in Java?

Tags: java, htmlunit, impressions, headless-browser

I am using the headless browser provide by [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

> I have loaded a webpage in a webClient. Now I want to generate mulitple impressions on a hyperlink (on the loaded webpage) just like we hover our mouse cursor on a link various times on a link in a webpage in a real web browser.

How can I do that through HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 1):

Hovering the mouse cursor on a hyperlink *does not* generate an impression.

- Clicking it generates an impression on the page to which it leads.
- Loading the link generates an impression for it (if it is an advertisement-link)

So, respectively:

- click the link with HtmlUnit and reload the target page multiple times
- reload the current page multiple times

Comment: It is an advertisement link. It will be counted for CPM (Click Per Mile) or CPI(Click per Impression). So I want to create those thousand impression through htmlunit.

Comment: this is 100% fraud and do NOT do it.

Comment: Actually this will be a fraud if use for generating money. But my intention is not that. Actually, I want to test myself against the search engines' capability of invalid clicks detection techniques. I have read a lot about those techniques and now want to test them... If I succeed in passing those techniques, then I will present those holes to the search engine companies which they haven't explored yet.... I know this will be very challenging but nothing is impossible. Everything is achievable.

Comment: ok, then my advice in the answer are plausible. They should work for you, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) frontend for HTMLUnit which makes this type of thing quite easy.

For example:

```
while is true
  GotoURL http://somepage.com/
  Click link:Buy Me!
end
```

Then just let it run until you have enough clicks. :)